# Usage of "^-" in grep

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, echo

I came across this in a bash script:

```
echo -e "${CONFIG_FILE}x" | grep -q "^-"
```

where `CONFIG_FILE` is some configuration file that has settings relevant to a build script.

What is the meaning of `'x'` in `"${CONFIG_FILE}x"` and what would the `-q "^-"` pattern do in grep?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any purpose to the `x` after `${CONFIG_FILE}`. Maybe there was an earlier version of the script where they didn't have quotes around the variable, so they wrote

```
echo -e ${CONFIG_FILE}x
```

In that case, the `x` ensures that there's an argument to `echo` even if the variable is empty. But the quotes solve that problem, so the `x` is no longer needed.

`grep -q "^-"` tests whether the first letter of the input is `-`. The regexp `^` matches the beginning of the line, and `-` matches itself. The `-q` option tells `grep` not to print the matching line, it just sets its exit status depending on whether it matched something or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
But what is the reason for doing a "^-"..meaning how does it help. I have seen this occur at many places now. Is there some logic or philosohy for doing this check on files?

Answer (score 0):

- `echo -e "${CONFIG_FILE}x"`

  Expands and prints the value of `CONFIG_FILE` variable followed by literal `x`.
- `grep -q "^-"`

  And quit if the output starts with `-` symbol.